# Como otimizar a paleta de cores de um Gif?

Tags: c#, imagem, compressão-de-imagem

Tenho um método que gera imagens através de um array de bytes que pego no banco de dados.

Os arquivos gerados estão entre 15 e 130 kb no formato gif, estavam maiores mas diminui um pouco as dimensoes.

Porém preciso que todos os arquivos tenham no máximo 100kb e não sei como otimizar a paleta de cores, reduzindo o numero para conseguir essa redução de tamanho.

Meu método é esse:

```
    try
    {
        System.Drawing.Image imageArquivo = this.byteArrayToImage(arqB);            
        imageArquivo = ScaleImage(imageArquivo, 450, 600);
        imageArquivo.Save(saveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        imageArquivo.Dispose();
        fichaExportacao.Exportado = 1;
        msgLog_Imagem = "    - Arquivo gerado na pasta " + saveLocation + "";
        itensExportados++;
    }
```

Comment: Acabei de realizar uma série de testes e percebi que para uma imagem com dimensões 450x600, o valor de 100kB é bem restritivo. Fiz uma comparação com diversas imagens, e o resultado foi o seguinte: tamanho do arquivo PNG SEMPRE <= tamanho GIF. Contudo, nem sempre esse tamanho foi <= 100kB. Principalmente porque o encoder utiliza uma paleta de cores fixa, e aplica [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither). Com isso, o tamanho do arquivo aumenta devido ao ruído. Tem como aumentar o limite em bytes ou diminuir as dimensões? Pode postar uma foto de exemplo para eu pensar em uma estratégia?

Comment: Não coube no outro comentário, mas consegui que as imagens tivessem tamanho <= 100kB, porém sem dithering, o que arruinou a qualidade da imagem gerada. Ainda não testei, mas do modo que vejo, sem dithering, para que a qualidade suba "um pouco", seria necessário alterar a paleta utilizada pelo encoder, e fazer com que ele utilizasse uma paleta criada especificamente para cada imagem, através do processo de quantização. Existe uma boa biblioteca para isso no [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66341/A-Simple-Yet-Quite-Powerful-Palette-Quantizer-in-C).

Comment: Legal carlos. Não posso colocar imagem aqui pois são confidenciais. Já está bem no limite das dimensões. Acho que a única solução seria mesmo essa de criar uma paleta exclusiva para cada imagem, mas por enqto não sei como fazer. A outra opção é que eles aceitem JPG. Em jpg consegui colocar todas abaixo de 50kb inclusive.

Comment: Pedi um exemplo de imagem para determinar se JPG pode ser aceitável. São gráficos com poucas cores, screenshots, ou são imagens como natureza/pessoas/lugares? JPG só fica bom para essa última categoria. Para as duas primeiras, ele até pode ficar aceitável, mas os *artifacts* da compressão ficarão em destaque e PNG terá um melhor resultado. Sobre como utilizar uma paleta para cada imagem, o [exemplo do CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66341/A-Simple-Yet-Quite-Powerful-Palette-Quantizer-in-C) realmente é bem legal ;)

Comment: Eh uma imagem de um cupom de preenchimento, fundo branco com campos a preencher, como nome, cargo, assinatura etc. A qualidade 45% do jpg fica aceitavel e permite ver direito as assinaturas e textos. Segunda feira vou tentar esse exemplo que voce passou.

Comment: Opa, sem problemas. Então, se a imagem ficasse em tons de cinza resolveria seu problema? Se eu postar uma resposta quantizando sua imagem para escala de cinza, com uma paleta com poucas cores, você aceitaria?

Comment: Em escala de cinza acho que atenderia tambem.

Comment: Ok, vou submeter uma resposta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme explicado nos comentários:

- A imagem é composta por um fundo branco e alguns textos/assinaturas/linhas
- Não é danoso utilizar tons de cinza para a imagem de saída

Assim, criei uma função que transforma uma imagem colorida (RGB) em 16 tons de cinza, e em seguida exporta para um GIF com uma paleta composta por 16 tons de cinza, linearmente espaçados:

```
//Cria uma paleta com os 16 tons de cinza desejados (distribuídos linearmente)
private static readonly System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapPalette Gray4Palette = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapPalette(new List<System.Windows.Media.Color>(new System.Windows.Media.Color[] {
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x88, 0x88, 0x88),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xDD, 0xDD, 0xDD),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE),
    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
}));

private static void SaveGifGray4(string saveLocation, Image image)
{
    //Obtém um array com os pixels originais da imagem, no formato 32bpp
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data = (image as Bitmap).LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    int stride = data.Stride;

    //Formato das componentes em originalPixels:
    //0 1 2 3, 4 5 6 7, ....
    //r g b a, r g b a, ....
    byte[] originalPixels = new byte[stride * image.Height];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, originalPixels, 0, originalPixels.Length);
    (image as Bitmap).UnlockBits(data);

    //Cria o array que irá armazenar os índices da paleta
    byte[] pixels = new byte[image.Width * image.Height];

    //Converte a imagem de 32bpp para 16 tons de cinza
    int offsetOut = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        int offsetIn = y * stride;
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++, offsetIn += 4, offsetOut++)
        {
            byte r = originalPixels[offsetIn], g = originalPixels[offsetIn + 1], b = originalPixels[offsetIn + 2];
            //Converte o RGB em um tom de cinza, conforme a intensidade luminosa relativa da cor
            int grayI = (((int)((0.2126f * (float)r) + (0.7152f * (float)g) + (0.0722f * (float)b)) >> 4) & 15);
            //Reduz para 16 possíveis valores
            pixels[offsetOut] = (byte)((255 * grayI) / 15);
        }
    }

    //Codifica a imagem para um arquivo GIF
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Palette = Gray4Palette;
    //Adiciona o único frame do GIF, a partir dos pixels já processados
    encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.Create(image.Width, image.Height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Indexed8, Gray4Palette, pixels, image.Width)));
    //Grava o arquivo através de um stream
    System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(saveLocation, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, System.IO.FileShare.None, 1024);
    encoder.Save(stream);
    stream.Close();
    stream.Dispose();
}
```

Por causa do trecho que envolve a compactação para GIF com maior controle e com mais opcões:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder encoder...
```

É necessário adicionar três referências ao projeto, para três `Assemblies` do .NET Framework:

- WindowsBase
- PresentationCore
- System.Xaml

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que você possa usar `Encoder.ColorDepth` para determinar a profundidade  de cor máxima (em bits).

```
   try
    {
        Encoder encoder = Encoder.ColorDepth;
        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        // Considerando 24 bits por pixel. Você pode alterar esse valor.
        EncoderParameter encoderParam = new EncoderParameter(encoder, 24L);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = encoderParam;

        System.Drawing.Image imageArquivo = this.byteArrayToImage(arqB);         
        imageArquivo = ScaleImage(imageArquivo, 450, 600);
        ImageCodecInfo gifCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/gif");
        imageArquivo.Save(saveLocation, gifCodecInfo, encoderParams);
        imageArquivo.Dispose();
        fichaExportacao.Exportado = 1;
        msgLog_Imagem = "    - Arquivo gerado na pasta " + saveLocation + "";
        itensExportados++;
    }
```

Método de obtenção do CodecInfo do Gif:

```
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
{
    int j;
    ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
    encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    for(j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
    {
        if(encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
            return encoders[j];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Interessante. Mas não tem overload para esses tres parametros. imageArquivo.Save(saveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif, myEncoderParameters); Tem esse aqui por exemplo: imageArquivo.Save(string filename,  ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)

Comment: Você pode usar o encoding de gif, então: ImageCodecInfo gifCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/gif");

Comment: De onde vem esse GetEncoderInfo()?

Comment: Já achei. Vou testar.

Comment: Amaury, tentei mudar os valores do parametro, mas nao surtiu nenhum efeito: EncoderParameter encoderParam = new EncoderParameter(encoder, 24L); testei 12L, testei 256, 2, 1... Qual a forma adequada para que eu tenha o minimo de qualidade?

Comment: Eu nunca testei, então não posso te responder com propriedade. Sugiro, então, que você tente outro encoder: "Encoder.Quality", no lugar de Encoder.ColorDepth. A sintaxe é a mesma, mas o parâmetro (no caso o 24L) representa o level de qualidade. Tente usar valores mais baixos pra ver se funciona.

Comment: Eu testei o Quality e o Compression, mas só serviram com JPG também. Estou ainda buscando uma solução sobre redução de paletas de cores GIF. Talvez eu acabe usando esse seu codigo com JPG mesmo, mas não posso marcar como resposta certa pois não faz o que a pergunta pede. De qualquer forma muito obrigado!